# Renaming factor levels in R with case_when

Tags: rename, case-when, factors, levels, recode

I am trying to rename the levels in my factor variable from 
    `levels(data$VAL_NETEJA)`
getting:

```
"0 = PÈSSIMA GESTIÓ"     "1"   "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"   "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10 = > >> > >EXCEL·LENT GESTIÓ" "NO HO SAP"  "NO CONTESTA"
```

with this code

```
data %>%
filter(!is.na(VAL_NETEJA))%>%
transmute(VAL_NETEJA=case_when(
VAL_NETEJA == "10 = EXCEL·LENT GESTIÓ"~ "10",
VAL_NETEJA == "0 = PESSIMA GESTIÓ"~ "0",
TRUE ~ as.character(VAL_NETEJA)
))%>%

filter(!is.na(VAL_NETEJA))%>%
transmute(VAL_NETEJA=case_when(
VAL_NETEJA == "NO HO SAP"~ "NA",
VAL_NETEJA == "NO CONTESTA"~ "NA",
TRUE ~ as.character(VAL_NETEJA)
))%>%
```

and it works, except for `"0 = PESSIMA GESTIÓ"~ "0"`. I was trying to try it with and without accents but it still won't change it. COuld I somehow resolve this issue with a function similar to contains or starts with for case_when?

Answer (score 0):

So, at the and I put the 0 one as the base and used this code:

```
data$neteja_levels<-data %>%
transmute(VAL_NETEJA=case_when(
VAL_NETEJA == "10 = EXCEL·LENT GESTIÓ"~ "10",
VAL_NETEJA == "1"~"1",
VAL_NETEJA == "2"~"2",
VAL_NETEJA == "3"~"3",
VAL_NETEJA == "4"~"4",
VAL_NETEJA == "5"~"5",
VAL_NETEJA == "6"~ "6",
VAL_NETEJA == "7"~ "7",
VAL_NETEJA == "8"~ "8",
VAL_NETEJA == "9"~ "9",
VAL_NETEJA == "NO HO SAP"~"NA",
VAL_NETEJA == "NO CONTESTA"~ "NA",
VAL_NETEJA == "NA"~ "NA",
TRUE ~ "0"
```

))